# How PHP read [your_name] from text area

Tags: php

### Check this:

```
Dear [NAME],
<br /><br />
Someone (hopefully you) requested a password reset at [SITE_URL].
<br /><br />
To reset your password, please follow the following link: [EMAIL_LINK]
```

---

In above lines there are names of the fields in [ ] in a text area of my php user management for email template.
Please tell me how PHP read i.e `[NAME]` this?
Is there a function.. if yes what is it and how?

Comment: Pretty Unclear what you want to achieve over here

Comment: I'm not very sure if you want to replace [] inner values with fields of a form or detect any name wrapped with [] and then, generate a form based on this. Can you be more explicit, please?

Comment: You can used `str_replace` function. i.e $text = str_replace('[NAME]', 'Your Name', $text);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to match all the keywords wrapped by square brackets:

```
$text = 'Dear [NAME],
<br /><br />
Someone (hopefully you) requested a password reset at [SITE_URL].
<br /><br />
To reset your password, please follow the following link: [EMAIL_LINK]';

preg_match_all('/\[([A-Z_]+)\]/', $text, $matches);
```

By `var_dump`ing the `$matches` variable you will get:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "[NAME]"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "[SITE_URL]"
    [2]=>
    string(12) "[EMAIL_LINK]"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "NAME"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "SITE_URL"
    [2]=>
    string(10) "EMAIL_LINK"
  }
}
```

So, let's suppose you will have an array of keywords to be replaced:

```
$keywords = array(
    'NAME' => 'Mihai MATEI',
    'SITE_URL' => 'http://example.com/',
    'EMAIL_LINK' => '<a href="mailto:contact@example.com">contact@example.com</a>',
);
```

You can replace the keywords in the template as:

```
foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $keyword) {
    $text = str_replace($matches[0][$key], $keywords[$keyword], $text);
}
```

Now if you `var_dump` the `$text` variable will get:

```
Dear Mihai MATEI,
<br /><br />
Someone (hopefully you) requested a password reset at http://example.com/.
<br /><br />
To reset your password, please follow the following link: <a href="mailto:contact@example.com">contact@example.com</a>
```

Comment: Wonderful Description, You cleared my Points, Thanks alot Mihai

Answer (score 0):

In php side just replace [NAME],[SITE_URL],[EMAIL_LINK]

Ex:

```
$message = $_POST['msg']; // this is you text area content
$message = str_replace('[NAME]', "My Name", $message);
$message = str_replace('[SITE_URL]', "www.xyz.com", $message);
$message = str_replace('[EMAIL_LINK]', "abc@gmail.com", $message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_replace`

```
$arrReplaceWords  = array('[NAME]', '[SITE_URL]', '[EMAIL_LINK]');
$arrReplaceValues = array('Your Name', 'Your Site Url', 'Your Email link');

$text = str_replace($arrReplaceWords, $arrReplaceValues, $text);
```

Comment: Thanks your answer its too much important for me, Thanks alot